# Increase Size of Navigation Buttons in Dolphin File Manager

Tags: kde, kubuntu, dolphin

How do you increase the size of these navigation buttons in Dolphin? :

[image]

Comment: Which version of dolphin are you using? 17.12.3 has a different interface, nicer IMO.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(Tested on dolphin 18.08.0)

To change the icon size: 
right click on icon bar -> select icon size -> choose a size

There is also a global setting, in: 
kde system settings -> icons -> configure icon size -> Main Toolbar

Comment: I'm a huge fan of right-click to configure. I can't believe I overlooked it. Thanks.